# Replacing Or Stripping Special Characters With Regex (Smarty)

Tags: regex, url, smarty, special-characters, strip-tags

in a part of my website i have a url that looks like this:

http://www.webizzi.com/mp3/search.html?q=+Hush+Hush+-+(Avril)++Lavigne's+

I would like to keep a cleaner url by stripping every special character that appears on the url except + but i also do not want to have something like ++ or + at the beginning or end of the url, the url should look like the one below

http://www.webizzi.com/mp3/search.html?q=Hush+Hush+Avril+Lavigne

what i have to process the url at the moment is:

```
{$config.siteurl}search.html?q={$tags[row].tag|regex_replace:"/\s+/":"+"|stripslashes}
```

Comment: After this, its a dead link I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input is everything after `?q=`

```
s/(^\++|\++$|\+\++|[\(\)]+)//g
```

In those last pair of brackets, you put any other characters you want stripped.

This matches one or more opening +'s, one or more closing +'s, two or more +'s anywhere, or one or more the special characters inside the brackets (so far, just parentheses) and replaces it with nothing – an empty string – zilch – nada.

---

I don't know jack about Smarty, but I think you should try something like

```
{$config.siteurl}search.html?q={$tags[row].tag|regex_replace:"/(^\++|\++$|\+\++|[\(\)]+)/":""|stripslashes}
```

I'm not quite sure if you need to escape the parentheses here, so if it doesn't work, lose some backslashes.

Comment: Thanks zilch, can you display an example with the cope i posted in the question pls, i have tried but i get errors on my mage display, i think i am not getting it right

Answer (score 0):

href="{$site_url}tests/tests/view/{$test.test_id}/{strtolower($test.test_name|replace:' ':'-'|regex_replace:'/(^++|++$|+++|[()]+)/':'')}">Test